# How can I using useCookie in Nuxt 3 - Laravel API directory?

Tags: laravel, single-page-application, nuxt3

I'm trying to get cookie with name XSRF_TOKEN when execute login function with laravel sanctum (breeze api) through "http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie" and nuxt 3, but I got undefinded value? What's step wrong from me?

...

[TOKEN SET UP ON COOKIE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heIY6.png)

```
const CSRF_COOKIE = ref("XSRF-TOKEN")
const CSRF_HEADER = ref("X-XSRF-TOKEN")

async function handleLogin() {
  await useFetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie', {
    credentials: 'include'
  });

  const token = useCookie(CSRF_COOKIE.value);

  console.log(token.value);
}
```

Token return undefinded value.